# How to ensure that remote computer was restarting and made command?

Tags: powershell, object, methods, output

I have a PS script which uses `Invoke-Command` and `Restart-Computer`. I would like to have a results and save them to file. I was thinking these cmdlets are objects something like `Get-Childitem` where is possible select members like `.Name` and save. Thus what they are? a methods? If yes, so from what objects? And finally how I will know that host e.g.`192.168.1.1` was restarting and did command sending by `Invoke-Command`?

```
foreach ($line in $FTPServer)
    {
        Start-Transcript -Path $results           
        Write-Host -Object "ftp url: $line"
        If (Test-Connection $line -Count 1)
        {
            Set-FTPConnection -Credentials $FTPCredential -Server $line -Session MySession -UsePassive -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            $Session = Get-FTPConnection -Session MySession
            if($session.UsePassive -eq "True"){$connect="OK"}
            else{$connect="!!!-FAIL-!!!"}

            foreach ($item in (Get-ChildItem .\Upload))
                {
                    Write-Host -Object "Uploading $item..."
                    $Send= Add-FTPItem -Session $Session -Path $FTPPlace -LocalPath .\Upload\$item -Overwrite -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                    $send >> .\RawData\sent.txt
                    if($Send.Name -eq $item.Name){$Rec="OK"}
                    else{$Rec="!!!-FAIL-!!!"}
                    $failTable += @{"FTPServer"=$line;"File"=$item;"Connected"=$connect;"Uploaded"=$Rec}
                    $FailTable.foreach{[PSCustomObject]$_} | Select-Object "FTPServer", "File","Connected", "Uploaded" | Out-file .\stats.txt

                }
            Enable-PSRemoting -Force
            Set-Item wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts -Value * -Force
            Restart-Service WinRm
            Test-WSMan $line
            Invoke-Command -ComputerName $line -scriptblock {cmd.exe /c "ewfmgr d: -commit"} -credential $FTPCredential

        Start-Transcript -Path $restarts
        Restart-Computer -ComputerName $line -Force -ThrottleLimit 50 -Credential $FTPCredential|Out-File restart.txt -Width 100
        Stop-Transcript

        } Else {"$line">> .\DownServers.txt}
        Stop-Transcript
    }
```

I would like to do the same things with `Restart-Computer` and `Invoke-Command` like I did with `Get-FTPConnection` and `Add-FTPItem`

Now my `.\stats.txt` looks like that

```
FTPServer   File                    Connected Uploaded
---------   ----                    --------- --------
192.168.1.1 ConfigurationKrKers.xml OK        OK      
192.168.1.1 test.txt                OK        OK
```

I want to have that content:

```
FTPServer   File                    Connected Uploaded  RunCMD Restarted
---------   ----                    --------- --------  ------ ---------
192.168.1.1 ConfigurationKrKers.xml OK        OK        OK     OK 
192.168.1.1 test.txt                OK        OK        OK     OK
```

Comment: Please show your code (a [mcve] to be precise) and an example of the desired output. We can't help you when all we got is a vague description like that.

Comment: Sounds like you could benefit from [workflows](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj134242.aspx)

Comment: Code and desired output appended.

Comment: You can put data into Windows log in your remote script, and after use get-eventlog from remote computer. Of course, you can read remote log with delay.

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/06/20/how-to-use-powershell-to-write-to-event-logs/ write to log in remote script

Comment: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_eventlog_remote.htm after you can read eventlog from remote computer. In event log you also can find message about windows restarting